# Sequences in $C(X)$

Tags: real-analysis

How would I go about proving this?

Let $X$ be a compact metric space. Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence in $C(X)$. If $(f_n)$ is uniformly convergent, show that $(f_n)$ is both uniformly bounded and equicontinuous.

Answer (score 0):

let the sequence $f_n$ be Uniformly convergent, since $f_n$'s are bounded and the sequence $f_n$ Uniformly convergent to the function $f$ ,$f$ is bounded therefore there exist $k_1$ a positive real number such that $|f(x)|<k_1$ for $x$, let $$M_n=sup_{x\in X}|f_n(x)-f(x)|$$, clearly $M_n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, $M_n$ is bounded sequence and therefore there exist $k_2$ positve real number such that $|M_n|<k_2$ for all $n$, that is $sup_{x\in X}|f_n-f|<k_2$ for all $n$ therefore for all $x\in X$, $|f_n(x)|<k_1+k_2$ for all $n$ this proves that $f_n$ is uniformly bounded on $X$